# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub when running Robolectric through Maven

Tags: android, maven, junit, intellij-idea, robolectric

Well, I'm having a strange bug. When I run my test through the IntelliJ, it passes without any problem. But if I run it using either the sure-fire plugin or the 'mvn clean test' command, I get the following exception:

```
shouldLoadMoreDataOnScrollBeyondTheThreshold(br.com.cybereagle.androidwidgets.listener.EndlessScrollListenerTest)  Time elapsed: 2.73 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:6)
    at br.com.cybereagle.androidwidgets.listener.EndlessScrollListenerTest.shouldLoadMoreDataOnScrollBeyondTheThreshold(EndlessScrollListenerTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:246)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:181)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
public class EndlessScrollListenerTest {

    private ListView listView;
    private EndlessScrollListener endlessScrollListener;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        listView = mock(ListView.class);

        when(listView.getHeaderViewsCount()).thenReturn(0);
        when(listView.getFooterViewsCount()).thenReturn(0);


        endlessScrollListener = spy(new TestEndlessScrollListener(5));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLoadMoreDataOnScrollBeyondTheThreshold() {
        doReturn(true).when(endlessScrollListener).hasMoreDataToLoad();

        assertTrue(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());

        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 2, 5, 20);

        assertFalse(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());

        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 15, 5, 20);

        assertTrue(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());


        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 21, 5, 40);

        assertFalse(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());

        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 35, 5, 40);

        assertTrue(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());

        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 38, 5, 60);

        assertFalse(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());

        doReturn(false).when(endlessScrollListener).hasMoreDataToLoad();

        endlessScrollListener.onScroll(listView, 55, 5, 60);

        assertFalse(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());


        verify(endlessScrollListener, atMost(6)).hasMoreDataToLoad();
        verify(endlessScrollListener, times(1)).loadMoreData(1);
        verify(endlessScrollListener, times(1)).loadMoreData(2);
        verify(endlessScrollListener, never()).loadMoreData(3);
    }

    private static class TestEndlessScrollListener extends EndlessScrollListener {

        private TestEndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
            super(visibleThreshold);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean hasMoreDataToLoad() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void loadMoreData(int page) {

        }
    }
}
```

The error happens in the first assertTrue:

```
assertTrue(endlessScrollListener.isLoading());
```

The most strange thing is that according to the stacktrace, it happens inside the assertTrue method.

These are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${android.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>${support.v4.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>${support.v7.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>${robolectric.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As I said, it works inside the IntelliJ.

Another detail is that I have another project that generates a JAR that is using the Robolectric normally both from IntelliJ and from Maven.

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: just small comment about your tests - it is too many assertions per test. Does number of these scroll events or coordinates change a lot? If not I would leave only one. I also would split test into two - one for check that is loading if there is data, one of that it's not loading if there is no data.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I'll try to improve this tests soon.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, my problem was that I was importing from the wrong package:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
```

I changed it to:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

Now it's working as expected. I don't know why it was working in the IntelliJ.

Comment: Fernando, try the 'fest-assert' library for assertions. It is quite addictive and extends assertions possibility and readbility

Comment: I'm starting to use it. Actually, I'm using only the fest-android yet. I have to get used to using the fest. Thank you for remembering.

Comment: For JUnit5 this will be org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions

Answer (score 5):

That is silly but moving dependency of junit and put it before android dependencies will solve your issue. So your maven should be like this:

```
depndencies
-junit
-android
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not my problem. I fixed it and I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Move the junit dependency up the chain on your referenced libraries and it will work. see [here](https://mcondev.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-at-junit-framework-testsuite-testsuite-java7-at-org-junit-internal-runners-junit38classrunner-junit38classrunner-java67-at-org-junit-internal-builders-junit3/)